# Backbone Facebook API Function

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, backbone.js

In my initialize function, within my router I have this piece of code:

```
AppRouter.prototype.initialize = function() {  
     Backbone.history.start();

     FB.api("/me", function(me) {
        name = me.name;
        alert('Hello ' + name)
     });
};
```

This alerts me with my name (Hello Danny).

However, I want to send this alert outside the FB.api function: My new code - which doesn't work and returns an alert with "null" is this:

```
AppRouter.prototype.initialize = function() {  
         Backbone.history.start();

         var name;
         name = null;

         FB.api("/me", function(me) {
            name = me.name;
         });
         alert('Hello ' + name)
    };
```

Can anyone suggest how I might go about doing this, any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: ah right. My plan was to save the results of that ajax call into a model. But I could see a way of doing that, if the above isn't possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've completely changed my structure after looking into how Backbone and the Facebook api can work together..

These two links tackle my problem and more:

[How do I use an FB.api(JS SDK) response outside of the callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652558/how-do-i-use-an-fb-apijs-sdk-response-outside-of-the-callback-function)

https://gist.github.com/2769429